# Visual Studio Intellisense describing the property/method not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I was using Visual Studio 2012 and it used to give the description of a property/method, which doesn't seem to work in VS2019. Is there an option that I will have to enable for this to work?
Below screesnhot is an example of File Input/Output operation:

- When I scroll/hover over ios::app, it should give a description "Append to the end of the file" which it does not.
- Second concern is that it is giving me a lot of other options as well (marked as * in VS). Is there an option to disable that permanently?
- Final concern is that, when I hover over a function, it will display the parameters that the function is expecting (Or list of suggestions if the function is overloaded). But for some reason, in the below case, it is displaying along with namespace. Is there an option to disable that?

**public static constexpr std::_losb::_Openmode std::_losb::app = (std::_losb::_Openmode)8**

[image]